# Does Windows 10 have .NET Core preinstalled?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

I have created a WinForms .NET Core app targeting .NET Core 3.1. I would like to publish it to a target machine with Windows 10 only as exe without having to make it self-contained, as this increases its size drastically. Would this work, or Windows 10 does not carry .NET Core in it?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: The Operating System comes with the .NET Standard framework, you have to download Core Runtime / Hosting if you intend to deploy Core to a target machine.  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Greg! If you post it I will accept as answer.
@manson I did not have a way to try it - did not have clean environment.

Comment: @checo I appreciate that, but this type of question should be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No window 10 does not come with pre-install .net core

Comment: This GitHub discussion tries to give answers to the why. https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6411